# What to use to create/animate a 2D sprite

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, graphics, sprite-kit

I want to create a simple endless runner game in swift (2D).
I'd like to know which software can i use to draw my character sprite, and make animation of its run in an easy and fast way.

What do you guys would use? I just need to specify something like "head", "body", "arms", "legs" and modify each "section", then take a snap

Thank you

Comment: have a look at [spine](http://esotericsoftware.com)

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should probably post this question on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You should use Apples 2D game engine called SpriteKit. This framework provides physics etc. like you need it.

You should take a closer look into the chapter Simulate Physics and check out the ["joints" section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW5) where you can connect different sprites.

But at first you should read [Introduction to SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and check the basics like [`SKSpriteNodes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html), [`SKTexture`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/index.html) and [`SKPhysicsBody`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html).

Comment: I don't know if i'm explaining right. I know i have to use sprite kit for developing my game.. But what i'm asking is what can i use to draw/create my sprite, so it's before developing the game: i have to draw my character and create the png's i'll use in the game. Thank you :)

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry I thought you need help finding the framework. Please update your question and add the sprite-kit tag. you should remove the draw tag instead

Answer (score 0):

You can Animate sprite Sheet using android device with Toon 2D App

Here is the link to download but it's paid app.

[App Download Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Thisana.Toon2D)

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwNR29qN6-I)